# Converting raw JSON to Facebook Standard Event using Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, json, facebook-pixel

Trying to write the javascript function required to translate the following track event in its JSON format to the matching Facebook Pixel event.

The following track event is placed on e-commerce site:

```
analytics.track('Product List Viewed', {
  category: 'Deals',
  list_id: 'hot_deals_1',
  products: [
    {
      category: 'Games',
      image_url: 'https://www.example.com/product/path.jpg',
      name: 'Monopoly: 3rd Edition',
      position: 1,
      price: 19,
      product_id: '507f1f77bcf86cd799439011',
      sku: '45790-32',
      url: 'https://www.example.com/product/path'
    },
    {
      category: 'Games',
      name: 'Uno Card Game',
      position: 2,
      price: 3,
      product_id: '505bd76785ebb509fc183733',
      sku: '46493-32'
    }
  ]
});
```

The above Javascript event is implemented on a website to collect the details of a Product List that a user viewed. The event is sent as raw JSON of the message as follows:

```
{
  "anonymousId": "70bbe85a-97db-49da-b36f-419dd858f3be",
  "context": {
    "ip": "12.179.173.270",
    "library": {
      "name": "analytics.js",
      "version": "3.8.2"
    },
    "page": {
      "title": "Toys R Us",
      "url": "https://toys-r-us.com"
    },
    "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.80 Safari/537.36"
  },
  "event": "Product List Viewed",
  "integrations": {},
  "messageId": "ajs-515fef4d8615e8f95d88988d0cb77e60",
  "originalTimestamp": "2019-06-18T17:16:11.546Z",
  "properties": {
    "category": "Deals",
    "list_id": "hot_deals_1",
    "products": [
      {
        "category": "Games",
        "name": "Monopoly: 3rd Edition",
        "position": 1,
        "price": 19,
        "product_id": "507f1f77bcf86cd799439011",
        "sku": "45790-32",
        "url": "https://www.example.com/product/path"
      },
      {
        "category": "Games",
        "name": "Uno Card Game",
        "position": 2,
        "price": 3,
        "product_id": "505bd76785ebb509fc183733",
        "sku": "46493-32"
      }
    ]
  },
  "receivedAt": "2019-06-18T17:16:11.579Z",
  "sentAt": "2019-06-18T17:16:11.554Z",
  "timestamp": "2019-06-18T17:16:11.571Z",
  "type": "track"
}
```

I am trying to write a Javascript function that would translate the raw JSON above to the standard Facebook’s fbq('track')function, that would translate the above JSON event to the synonymous ViewContent standard event in Facebook.

I believe the final output should look something like the final output below, but I don't know where to start in developing the Javascript function to transform the raw JSON into the final product:

```
<script>
fbq('track', 'ViewContent', {content_name: ‘Monopoly: 3rd Edition’,
  content_category: ‘Games’,
  content_ids: ['45790-32'],
  content_type: 'product',
  value: 19,
  currency: 'USD'
 },
{
  content_name: ‘Uno Card Game’,
  content_category: ‘Games’,
  content_ids: ['46493-32'],
  content_type: 'product',
  value: 3,
  currency: 'USD'
 }
);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Next time, please spend some time trying it out yourself and provide where you got stuck.

Here's an example of typing the data according to the fbq event.

```html
<script>
  
  const data = {
    // ....
    // ....
    properties: {
      category: "Deals",
      list_id: "hot_deals_1",
      products: [
        {
          category: "Games",
          name: "Monopoly: 3rd Edition",
          position: 1,
          price: 19,
          product_id: "507f1f77bcf86cd799439011",
          sku: "45790-32",
          url: "https://www.example.com/product/path"
        },
        {
          category: "Games",
          name: "Uno Card Game",
          position: 2,
          price: 3,
          product_id: "505bd76785ebb509fc183733",
          sku: "46493-32"
        }
      ]
    }
    // ....
    // ....
  }
  
  const modifiedData = data.properties.products.map(({category, sku, price}) => ({
    content_category: category,
    content_ids: [sku],
    content_type: 'product',
    value: price,
    currency: 'USD'
  }));
  
  console.log(modifiedData)

  //fbq('track', 'ViewContent', modifiedData);
  
  </script>
```